# Add footer text and page number in same line on docx file with docx4j java

Tags: java, docx4j

I am trying to add small text (left side) and page number (right side) on the footer of a .docx document **in the same line**

so far I can add the text and the page number but in 2 lines

```
TextVersionv02312     
                                                                                   1
```

But I need it

```
TextVersionv02312                                                                        1
```

The code that I am using to add text and page number is:

```
private static Ftr createFooter(WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage, String content, ObjectFactory factory, Part sourcePart, InputStream is) throws IOException, Throwable {
        Ftr footer = factory.createFtr();
        P paragraph = factory.createP();
        R run = factory.createR();
        /*
         * Change the font size to 8 points(the font size is defined to be in half-point
         * size so set the value as 16).
         */
        RPr rpr = new RPr();
        HpsMeasure size = new HpsMeasure();
        size.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(16));
        rpr.setSz(size);
        run.setRPr(rpr);
        Text text = new Text();
        text.setValue(content);
        run.getContent().add(text);
        paragraph.getContent().add(run);
        footer.getContent().add(paragraph);

        // add page number
        P pageNumParagraph = factory.createP();
        addFieldBegin(factory, pageNumParagraph);
        addPageNumberField(factory, pageNumParagraph);
        addFieldEnd(factory, pageNumParagraph);
        footer.getContent().add(pageNumParagraph);
        return footer;
    }

private static void addPageNumberField(ObjectFactory factory, P paragraph) {
        R run = factory.createR();
        PPr ppr = new PPr();
        Jc jc = new Jc();
        jc.setVal(JcEnumeration.RIGHT);
        ppr.setJc(jc);
        paragraph.setPPr(ppr);
        Text txt = new Text();
        txt.setSpace("preserve");
        txt.setValue(" PAGE   \\* MERGEFORMAT ");
        run.getContent().add(factory.createRInstrText(txt));
        paragraph.getContent().add(run);

    }
```

I have been thinking to add a table or something like that on the footer to put the elements in the same line, But it seems that I am overcomplicating the stuff.

or maybe I can append the page number to the text paragraph

what do you think?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it any way you can in Word, for example, with tab stops.  (Or as you say, tables, but I'd use say a centre aligned then a right aligned tab if you wanted centre then right)

Easiest is to get it right in Word, then use the docx4j webapp or Docx4j Helper Word AddIn, to generate corresponding Java code from that sample document.

Comment: Finally, could not use tabs characters. However, with spaces, it worked .the problem was when the margins of the document change. Fortunately for me, the requirements changed. thanks!